# how to read and edit json file from internet

Tags: flutter, dart, logic, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I want to use a JSON file as temp data saving and edit it.

this is how I get data from local, I want to get file from internet and edit it.

```
 var mydata =  json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('/assets/testjson.json'));
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this helps you? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: If you want to get json response, First you have to make http network call. Based on the response you  can manipulate the data. Check below articles for more info.
https://blog.logrocket.com/networking-flutter-using-dio/

Comment: @WaelAlshabani  I want to get data from a " JSON file " from the internet. aren't i clear in the question?